# Difference between Admob Ads and Firebase Ads

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I'm trying to migrate from Google analytics to the new Firebase analytics but I noticed there are libraries for ads too. Are firebase ads going to replace admob ads as well? Should I keep using admob via google play services? Or make a switch to the Firebase SDK? What's the difference anyways?

Comment: Seems like Firebase is for tracking users interactions in your application.

Comment: Not just tracking users with Firebase you have all in one place admob , analytic , crash reporting , realtime database ,hosting , storage, authentication etc.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Happily, these are the same thing! The 'firebase-ads' dependency just brings in the existing 'play-services-ads' library and the 'firebase-analytics' library. The Firebase SDK is part of Google Play services, so no need to worry about migrating, just update to the latest version.

Exactly as Kastriot says, the main integration is between Firebase Analytics and AdMob, but the AdMob SDK is still the same service you're already familiar with.

Comment: Just to add that curious ones can confirm that by looking at the dependencies in the POM file (ANDROID_SDK\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\firebase\firebase-ads\9.0.0\firebase-ads-9.0.0.pom)

Comment: If I migrate an Admob app to firebase, will old versions of my app (with old Admob API) stop loading ads, or will they keep working?

Comment: They'll keep right on working. The ad units don't need to change, or anything like that.

Comment: So I don't need to move to firebase admod if i don't need analytics? Right?

Comment: Can I safely just change the gradle file lines, from Admob to Firebase, and it will work exactly the same? Is it even worth it? Will Admob repository always get updated, just like Firebase ads?

Comment: I use Admob and Firebase Admob in two different applications. If you look at the statistics on profit, we can say that Firebase Admob has a reward of 20 times less.

Answer (score 3):

> Linking your app(s) to Firebase enables Firebase Analytics and AdMob
>   to work together more closely. By choosing to link your app to
>   Firebase, you allow more of your Analytics data to be used by AdMob
>   independent of your Firebase Analytics Data Sharing Settings.

Check [Admob - Google Support](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6360054?hl=en&ref_topic=3499164) for more information and [Admob - Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/admob-firebase#why_use_firebase)

Answer (score 2):

I used to use https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob

Later, use https://github.com/unity-plugins/Firebase-Admob-Unity

Found no difference between the two, they use the same admob library, the same

code to achieve. Firebase just retains a previous admob interface