# Which dependency is needed to use admob ads?

Tags: android, firebase, admob, android-gradle-plugin

I am confused after the new update of admob 
Which dependency should be included to use  admob ads?

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2
(or)
com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2
```

For more info. you can visit

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start#project-level_buildgradle_excerpt

[Difference between Admob Ads and Firebase Ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322451/difference-between-admob-ads-and-firebase-ads)

Comment: the answer is not clear which dependency should i have to use for admob ads

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/admob-firebase "The best way to use AdMob is with Firebase, but for those publishers who aren't ready to make the switch just yet, Google Mobile Ads will remain available as a standalone SDK. Android publishers can continue to import the play-services-ads Gradle artifact without using the Firebase plugin" This means you can use `play-services-ads` if you don't want Firebase or `firebase-ads` if you do.